# Jump to a specific part of page

Tags: html, css

I've experimented with a simple "feature" on my Shopify theme, where I want a link to jump to a specific part of the page - quite simple, and I've done it like this.

```
<a href="#jumpto">Jump to section</a>

<span id="jumpto">The section i want to jump to</span>
```

It works like a charm, but! I have a sticky header, where the "The section i want to jump to" is hidden behind. Is there any way, with css, push it a bit down down, so "The section I want to jump to" is shown, right beneath the header.

Basically I want the `span` element to appear for example 50px beneath the header.

My setup looks something like this

```
<div id="sectiona">
</div>

<span id="jumpto">The section i want to jump to</span>
<div id="sectionb">
</div>
```

If i use margin og padding, the gab between would be to big.

Comment: If you cannot add extra padding, you will need a js solution to scroll back the amount of your header

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for how that might look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to solve your problem and make smooth scrolling as well.

```js
$('a[href*="#"]').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top - 50
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: How can I add it to my HTML, not the sharpest in JavaScript? ;-)

Comment: Just right before you end your <body> add the javascript like so 
<script type="text/javascript">
 //Your javascript code
</script>

Comment: Great thank you! Works perfectly. Can I use a differet rule in the javascript on mobile?

Comment: What do you mean by different rule? The code should work perfectly on mobile as well :))

Comment: It does, but i want it to show just a few pixels more below, is it possible?

Comment: Oh absolutely. You just have to change the scrollTop according to your preferences. In the example above I used -50 from top offset, but if you want lower, you can use -40 or sth like that, whatever it fits to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203041/discussion-between-rasmus-kjeldsen-and-armedin-kuka).

Answer (score 0):

This might not the prettiest solution, but it should do the trick. By having an empty span (`.jump-marker`) acting as the jumping point you can offset the position where the anchor jumps to.

```
.jump-marker {
  position: absolute;
  margin: -120px 0 0;
}
```

You could also use JS/jQuery to offset the scroll distance by your header height and also allow smooth scrolling, which is much more pleasing to the eye, but that wasn't asked for! :)

Example:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 120px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,0.25);
  height: 100px;
}

.more-content {
  height: 1000px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

section {
  position: relative;
}

.jump-marker {
  position: absolute;
  margin: -120px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<header></header>

<a href="#jumpto">Jump to section</a>

<div class="more-content"></div>

<section>
  <div class="section-content">
    <span id="jumpto" class="jump-marker"></span>
    The section i want to jump to
  </div>
</section>

<div class="more-content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I make a basic header fixed and made the links  tag link offset from the place I want to link too. This solution is really rough but can work with good CSS and placing
html:

```html
<div class="jumpTo">
    <a id="0">0</a>
</div>
<h2>0</h2>
```

css:

```css
.jumpTo{
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ovcx2t9z/

or a fiddle based on the Jquery solution

> You can use JavaScript to solve your problem and make smooth scrolling as well.

```js
$('a[href*="#"]').click(function(){
   $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top - 50
   }, 500);
   return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qy03xb1r/2/

Answer (score -1):

How is the page layed out? Have you tried using padding or margin adjustments like.. padding-top:50px; or margin-top:50px.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your reply.
Yes i've tried that, but then my problem is the space between the previous section and the section I want to go to.

I'll update my question - just a minute.